# Is there a format function available in a Lightning Component controller or helper?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

The [Dynamically Populating Label Parameters](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/labels_parameters.htm?search_text=format) documentation describes how you can:

> Output and update labels using the format() **expression** function

e.g.:

```
{!format($Label.mySection.myLabel, v.attribute1, v.attribute2)}
```

But I need to build some error strings in a controller and in a helper not directly in the component markup.

I see that in the [Using Custom Labels](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/labels_value_provider_platform.htm) documentation a label value can be obtained in JavaScript via:

```
$A.get("$Label.namespace.labelName")
```

But is there a way to get hold of the `format` function? (Simply calling it gives me "format is not defined" in both controller and helper.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Would prefer a platform function or a way to get to the platform function so please answer if you have a way to do that.

But for now I have added this to my helper:

```
format: function(string) {
    var outerArguments = arguments;
    return string.replace(/\{(\d+)\}/g, function() {
        return outerArguments[parseInt(arguments[1]) + 1];
    });
},
```

which is a slight tweak of the accepted answer to [MessageFormat in javascript (parameters in localized UI strings)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353408/messageformat-in-javascript-parameters-in-localized-ui-strings) so that the substitution values don't have to be wrapped in an array.

**PS**

Better to use the build-in `format` function - see [How to add dynamic variable to custom label in lightning javascript helper class](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/166824/how-to-add-dynamic-variable-to-custom-label-in-lightning-javascript-helper-class).

Comment: I had a similar requirement and I did exactly what you have done.

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce have initially exposed the support for `$A.util.format()` in their [documentation by mistake](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_lightning_labels_dynamic_params.htm).

Then they later removed it from [their documentation](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_lightning_additional.htm). This code will not compile from api version 40 or later.

Here is another [related post](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000l3ZwQAI)

Currently recommended method seem to be to use javascript `replace()` function. It would be really good if Salesforce can enable this functionality natively, but for the moment we'll have to live this :(

Comment: Agreed; not sure it used to be documented but good that it is.

Comment: @KeithC I just tried to use this and it seems Salesforce have removed the reference to the api in Winter 17. https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_lightning_additional.htm. It would be really useful to have it though :(

Comment: Removed from the docs or removed from the code or both?

Comment: Removed from both now. Code won't compile with `A.util.format()` method. So we probably need to mark this answer as not correct. Apologies, their documentation is pretty confusing.

Comment: OK moved the accepted back again... as its your answer would you mind editing it yourself?